# What are all the ways to check if a file exists in ruby without shelling out?

Tags: ruby

What are all the ways to check if a file exists using Ruby's core classes/modules without shelling out?

Would also appreciate reasons why choosing one method over another makes sense. For example: Using `Dir['**/*'].grep(/foo/)` is the shortest way I've found to match paths using a regex.

However, I think `Pathname.new('.').find.any? { |pn| pn.fnmatch? "*foo*" }` is a good option because [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) is a cross-platform solution that usually seems to "just work".

Are there any solutions/classes/modules I've missed? Also, would appreciate answers that involve speed/efficiency analysis.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'pathname'

class TestTouch < Minitest::Test
  include FileUtils
  attr_reader :foo
  def setup
    @foo = Pathname.new('foo')
    foo.delete if foo.exist?
  end

  def teardown
    foo.delete if foo.exist?
  end

  def test_touch
    touch foo
    cwd = Pathname.new('.')
    assert cwd.find.to_a.map(&:to_s).grep(/foo/).any?
    assert cwd.find.any? { |pn| pn.fnmatch? "*foo*" }
    assert cwd.join('foo').exist?
    assert Dir['**/*'].grep(/foo/)
    assert Dir.glob('**/*').grep(/foo/)
    assert !Dir.glob('foo').empty?
    assert File.exist?('foo')
  end
end
```

Comment: You have `File.exist?` in your code. What's the problem? That's what you need. You have all the tools you need here, including the Pathname module. There's no shell involved in any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

```
Pathname.exist?(NAME)
FileTest.exist?(NAME)
Pathname.file?(NAME)
FileTest.file?(NAME)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
File.exist?(fname)
File.file?(fname)
```

Sometimes though, if you need to check existence and open the file in an atomic operation is can be best to just open the file and handle the case of a missing file by rescuing the exception.

Why would it be a good idea? This mostly applies to infrastructure code on the backend when you deal with databases and caching layers. Sometimes it can be critical that your code is not affected if the file is deleted or replaced between taking the branch and consuming the content—when a file is deleted the handle remains open and can still be used!

```
begin
  File.open(fname) { ... }
rescue Errno::ENOENT => e  
  ...
end
```

`ENOENT` is the C library error code for "file not found" for a complete list of all error codes see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html). Most of Ruby's file handling is basically just a thin wrapper around the underlying C libraries. As you might have already noticed from browsing the `File` class.

Comment: What that your downvote? Sometime it can be critical to get the handle on the open file immediately so you code is not affected if the file is deleted while you taken that branch. When a file is deleted the handle remains open and can still be used, this is not what some people expect.

Comment: Nope, I was just curious. I never thought of this, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
File.exists?(NAME)
```

? Note that this also returns true if NAME is, for instance, a directory.

Comment: `exists?` is deprecated in favor of `exist?`

Comment: None of Ruby's predicate functions ends with an `s` expect for this typo which has thus been deprecated.

Comment: I even define aliases to write `"string".is_an?(Array)`.

Comment: This reminds me on the good old times of COBOL, where the design goal was to "create a language which looks like plain English"   ;-)